# Gradle 6.0 deprecated message with IvyArtifactRepository.layout(String, Closure) method

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

When I use `--warning-mode all` in my gradle build, I am getting the following message:

The IvyArtifactRepository.layout(String, Closure) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Please use the IvyArtifactRepository.patternLayout(Action) method instead.

When I add the `--stacktrace` parameter, I get the full context, but there is no reference to my build / code in the stac trace, so not sure how to address this.

### Here is the stack trace I got:

The IvyArtifactRepository.layout(String, Closure) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Please use the IvyArtifactRepository.patternLayout(Action) method instead.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultIvyArtifactRepository.layout(DefaultIvyArtifactRepository.java:299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.listener.ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener$_createIvyRepo_closure3.doCall(ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.groovy:104)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
        at org.gradle.util.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:70)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:154)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:105)
        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:166)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.addRepository(DefaultArtifactRepositoryContainer.java:89)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.ivy(DefaultRepositoryHandler.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultRepositoryHandler.ivy(DefaultRepositoryHandler.java:114)
        at org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler$ivy$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.listener.ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.createIvyRepo(ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.groovy:101)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.listener.ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.defineResolvers(ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.groovy:81)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.listener.ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.evaluate(ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.groovy:69)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.listener.ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener$_projectsEvaluated_closure4.doCall(ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.groovy:126)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
        at org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.listener.ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.projectsEvaluated(ProjectsEvaluatedBuildListener.groovy:124)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingInvocationHandler$1$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:240)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:58)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingInvocationHandler$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:236)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingInvocationHandler.invoke(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:233)

Comment: I did post the full run on the Gradle site - see https://scans.gradle.com/s/5opyqj6szezyi/deprecations?openUsages=WzMsNF0#deprecation-5

Comment: Plugin name and version, please?

Comment: id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' version '4.8.1'
from https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin found the latest was '4.9.0', but getting the same error with that version too.

Comment: I pushed an updated run to gradle site, with latest versions - see https://gradle.com/s/ruzvvvjvtzwx4

Comment: Thanks, Eric. We're checking and will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are just starting testing the readiness of our plugins towards the future release of Gradle 6. By the release time, we'll make sure to refactor so we won't use the deprecated methods.

Comment: You mean with Gradle 5.x ?

Comment: I mean, testing to get ready to Gradle 6.0 – cleaning up the warnings towards Gradle 6. I updated the answer.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to not get this message? Using gradle5.3 and the latest plugin 4.9.3

Comment: We'll update our plugin soon. Sorry about the inconvenience.